# Fixed points and Bijection question.

Tags: computer-science, fixed-points

This is the problem.

Assume that the letters from A to Z are numbered from 0 to 25, and let f be a cipher function such that f (x) = (ax + b) mod 26.

● Determine all the possible values that a (0≤ a <26) can take so that f
be bijective.

● For those values of a that make f bijective, indicate which are the
possible b-values that ensure that each letter will be mapped to a letter
different.

This is my guess:

Being $f(x) = (ax + b)$ $mod$  $26$ and $a = 3,5,7,9,11,15,17,19,21,23,25$.

Now my question is:

Does $f (x)$ have to be a fixed points function?

Do I have to choose values of b that make the function be a fixed point function, in order to ensure that each letter will be mapped to a letter
different.?

Comment: What is $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Sorry, they are sets.

Comment: What value does $b$ have to take in order for *what*?

Comment: Now I edited I just missclicked the 'ctrl v' botton on the question when I edited it.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?  You haven't told us.  The answer you get for $A=\{0\}$ will be different from the answer you get with $A=\{0,13\}$, e.g.

Comment: Are you asking:   given any $a$ in the list and any $b$, must the function $x\mapsto ax+b \pmod {26}$ have a fixed point?  That is, must the congruence $ax+b\equiv x\pmod {26}$ have a solution?  Something else?

Comment: No, the entire problem is that with those 'a' values that make the function bijective, I need to find 'b' values in order to map 1 element of $A$ to only 1 element of $B$ @lulu

Comment: Your post is extremely vague.  You introduce seemingly arbitrary sets $A,B$ without defining them or using them.  Perhaps it would clarify your thinking if you wrote out an explicit example.  Say $a=3,b=0$.  Does that example work for you?  If so, why?  Does it fail for you?  If so, why?

Comment: @lulu I will fixed it and write the entire problem.

Comment: @lulu Just finished, tell me now if you understand my question.

Comment: @lulu Do I have to choose values of b that make the function be a fixed point function?

Comment: Again, work examples.  Consider $f_1(x)=3x\pmod {26}$ and $f_2(x)=3x+1\pmod {26}$.  Show that one of those has a fixed point and the other does not.  These sort of problems always get clearer if you work examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131069/discussion-between-rustik-ideas-and-lulu).